# Does Intellij have an auto replace feature like Toad?

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

Does `Intellij` have an `auto replace` feature like `Toad`?

keyboard : `ss + spacebar ==> select * from`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ has `live templates`.

For example enter the following code and place the cursor inside the curly braces:

```
public class MyClass {
    // put cursor under this line

}
```

Now type `psvm` and hit `TAB`, the following will appear

```
public class MyClass {
    // put cursor under this line
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

There are many live templates. The one in this example means "public static void main" (`psvm`) - you can research them all yourself. Note that many depend on context.

IntelliJ documentation: [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html)

Comment: Hi, that's great , can you tell me what is the short cut for System.out.println()?

Comment: Try `sout` and `tab`.